# v-show or v-if div shifted the others div into the parent container

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I would like to add dynamically image (check arrow) into a div which contains other div information (image + texte).

This adding means that users owned this "object" in the application. He can added or deselected this object on the fly.

The result of this action is appear or disappear arrow on the fly.

This process run perfectly in my vue.js component. But I can view appear an offset each time that arrow appears like this :

[image]

*I try to use v-if or v-show vue.js directives but the result is the same.*

I don't want to have a new offset appear when action to checked item is launch.

**this is the HTML template** :

```
<div id="container">

    <div @click="checkedItem(key.id)" class="container-item" v-for="(key, value) in objects">
        <div class="check" v-show="checked[key.id]">
            <img height="35" width="35" src="../../../static/checked.png"></img>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/75/75/?image=25" alt="logo"></img>
        </div>
        <div class="name">{{ key.name }}</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**This is the CSS stylesheet component** :

```
<style scoped>

    #container
    {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .container-item
    {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        margin: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
    }

    .container-item div.check
    {
        z-index: 3;
        position: relative;
        left: 20px;
        bottom: 15px;
    }
    .container-item div.check > img
    {
        height: 35px;
        width: 35px;
    }

    .container-item div.image
    {
        z-index: 2;
        border: 1px solid blue;
    }

    .container-item div.name
    {
        z-index: 1;
        position: relative;
        top: 12px;
        right: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 45px;
        width: 150px;
        max-height: 50px;
        border: 1px solid blue;
        background-color: yellow;
    }

</style>
```

**And the checkedItem method component** :

```
    checkedItem: function (id)
    {
        let isChecked = this.checked[id] ? true : false
        isChecked ? this.checked[id] = false : this.checked[id] = true
    },
```

*How can "add" DOM node HTML into HTML template component vue.js whitout create a new offset on the fly ?*

Comment: Just to clarify: all you need is a different offset based on the checked status of the item?

Comment: No I want the exactly same offset. I don't want to container move on the right after added green arrow check.

Comment: That's purely a CSS thing: just use `position: absolute` on `.container-item div.check`. You don't want the presence or absence of the check image to influence your layout, so you need to take it out from the flow: this is done by using absolute positioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we have discussed in the comments, this is purely a CSS thing. What you want is to take `div.check` out from the layout flow, so that it does not influence the positioning of other elements. This can be done by adding `position: absolute` to its ruleset. For that to work, remember to add `position: relative` to its parent, too:

```css
.container-item {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 30px 30px 30px 30px;

    /* Allow div.check to be positioned relative to its parent */
    position: relative;
}

.container-item div.check {
    z-index: 3;
    left: 20px;
    bottom: 15px;

    /* Take the check icon out of layout flow */
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: I confirm that solution work for me. Important to set position relative for parent and after position absolute of child (2 properties is important).